# What is the difference between go-Cobra PersistentFlags and Flags?

Tags: go, go-cobra

I'm trying to figure out whats is the difference between PersistentFlags and Flags in go-Cobra, and when should we use each of them.
I've read [this](https://suraj.io/post/cobra-persistent-flag/?utm_campaign=Master%20the%20World%20of%20Golang&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Revue%20newsletter) but I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When using Cobra you define a top level command:

```sh
prog
```

This top level command has sub-commands.  For instance, suppose we have three sub-commands, `init`, `start`, and `stop`.

```sh
prog init [-i]         # initialize, but don't start anything: -i means ignore
prog start [-f] [-q]   # after init, start: -f=fast, -q=quiet
prog stop [-f]         # stop: -f=force
```

The `-i` flag is only for `init`, so we add a `-i` flag to the `init` subcommand.

The `-q` flag is only for `start`, so we add a `-q` flag to the `start` subcommand, and so on.

Now we'd like to add a debug mode to *every* command.  We could go into each command and add a `--debug` flag ... but we can also just set a *persistent* flag for the root command.  This persistent flag will now be available in *every* sub-command.

If you have a sub-command that has sub-sub-commands, you can set a persistent flag in the sub-command to make that flag appear in every sub-sub-command, and so on.

Answer (score -3):

**Flags** returns the complete FlagSet that applies to this command (local and persistent declared here and by all parents).

**PersistentFlags** returns the persistent FlagSet specifically set in the current command.